# How to find out the quality of machine translation systems?

Tags: google-translate, translate, machine-translation, software-quality, deepl

I know that there are various metrics for measuring the quality of machine translation systems, for example:

- Bleu
- METEOR
- Lepor

Are there somewhere in the public domain metric results for popular translation systems? For example, such as:

- Google translate
- DeepL
- Yandex Translate
- Microsoft translate
- Promt
- Apertium
- Openlogs
- Papago
- Fanyi Baidu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine translation quality is annually evaluated at the [Conference on Machine Translation](http://www.statmt.org/wmt19/). Most of the evaluated systems are experimental systems from universities, but most of the systems you mention participate as well. You the results of last year's *human* evaluation in Table 11 on page 24 of the [conference findings](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W19-5301.pdf).

Most of the systems you mentioned participate anonymously under acronyms `online-?`, but you can often guess which system is which.

Answer (score 0):

There are some comparisons out there, but they're mainly for marketing purposes - people love rankings.

The comparisons use either metrics like BLEU that require reference translations, or recently AI, or even actual human evaluation.  They choose content for various domains, and use generic systems.

The thing is, the result of metric for a system is a factor of 1) the source content 2) the system and 3) the reference translation or AI or human evaluator style.

But in practice, you usually care about how systems does on *your* content, often with regard to *your* style, target locale and so on.

And you don't care about results for generic systems, you care about *your* systems - because if you care enough to bother with any of this, you care enough to do some basic customization.

As a concrete example of a problem with ranking generic systems with BLEU or even human evaluation, it is often thrown off by something like locale-specific spellings, punctuation preferences or tags.

So then it becomes more a question of which system has the best customization.  Or the *easiest* customization.  Or the locales... Or...  And there are all sorts of gotchas, for example, you can't customize Google Translate for a language pair like German to French, that isn't to or from English.

So many people asked me "What's the best engine?", that I founded the non-profit Machine Translate Foundation to provide open information, because there's no simple answer.

It now lists 77 [machine translation APIs](https://machinetranslate.org/apis), with data on key features like language support, customization and integrations.

---

If you do find or customize a few systems that fit your requirements, and you're ready to compare them, then the basic playbook is something like this:

### 1. Compile your eval set or eval sets

It is often useful to have a few different sets, with different types of content, to understand if a system does better on one or the other.

You could even take it further and label different lines automatically, for example segments with tags.  That way you'll know which system does best on those.

### 2. Get your machine translations from each

### 3. Look into the translations yourself

There is no replacement for actually looking, to get a feel and make sure there is no obvious issue.

### 4. Apply your metric

You have a few options.

A. Use a [metric](https://machinetranslate.org/metrics) like BLEU, if you have human reference translations for the source

B. Get human post-edits or labels for the output of each system

Again, look into the data, like edits, don't just take the aggregate metric blindly.

---

But the point is, by actually evaluating *your* content, using *your* style, and *your* systems, you get a better set of systems to rank, and a better ranking no matter which method you use.